# how to change title and description on Next and Previous button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

*EDIT: This question is apparently related to the [jQuery Carousel Evolution](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-carousel-evolution/490018) plugin's UI.*

How would I change the title and description on next and previous button?

Also, when i load the page and when carousal will display that time 1st title and description should display bydefault. Please solve my problem. I am shared the link also , please see below

```
$(document).ready(function () {});

var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/0155DF7A9B0DF819?v=2&alt=json&callback=?';
var videoURL = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
$.getJSON(playListURL, function (data) {
    var list_data = "";
    $.each(data.feed.entry, function (i, item) {
        var feedTitle = item.title.$t;
        var feedescription = item.media$group.media$description.$t;
        var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
        var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
        var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
        var url = videoURL + videoID;
        var thumb = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoID + "/hqdefault.jpg";
        list_data += '<div><a href= "#" ><img src="' + thumb + '" width="213px" height="141px"/></a></div>';
    });
    $(list_data).appendTo(".slides");
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        carouselWidth: 930,
        carouselHeight: 330,
        directionNav: true,
        shadow: true,
        buttonNav: 'bullets'
    });

    var cnt = 0;
    $(".nextButton").click(function () {
        var len = $(this).siblings(".slides").children(".slideItem").length;
        var a = cnt++;
    });

    $(".prevButton").click(function () {
        var len = $(this).siblings(".slides").children(".slideItem").length;
        var a = cnt++;
    });
});
```

Demo Link :- http://jsfiddle.net/4HSpH/4

Thanx in Advance ...

Answer (score 1):

For question 1, you can use jQuery to add your title attributes after carousel initialization. The plugin you've selected doesn't seem to have a very robust API for that sort of thing.

http://jsfiddle.net/4HSpH/6

```
$('.prevButton').attr('title', 'My previous button');
$('.nextButton').attr('title', 'My next button');
```

To get your title to populate on load, try this after the code above:

```
$("#title").text($items.filter(function () {
    return $(this).css("top") == "0px";
}).find("a").attr("title"));
```

Comment: and what about description ?

Comment: And what about some gratitude?